# jquery mobile 1.1.1 causes navbar to show all buttons as active

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Since upgrading my web application to jquery mobile 1.1.1 I have a problem with the navbar. Although only one button has the active class, all buttons are in the active color. Any idea what is going wrong? This is an example of the header of one of my pages:

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainMenu" class="menuPage" data-theme="b">    

        <div data-role="header" data-posistion="fixed" data-id="constantNav">
            <h1>Main menu</h1>  

            <div id="navbarHolder">
               <div data-role='navbar'>
                  <a href='main.jsp' class='ui-state-persist ui-btn-active' data-icon='home' style='width: 10%;'></a>
                  <a href='page1.jsp' class='ui-state-persist' data-icon='icon1' style='width: 10%;'></a>
                  <a href='page2.jsp' class='ui-state-persist' data-icon='icon2' style='width: 10%;'></a>
                  ... other buttons
               </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /header -->
```

Thanks in advance!

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ui-state-persist class from the inactive bars and the problem will be solved.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm glad I could help Frank :)